# Reset local AppEngine datastore via Ant (while devserver is running)

Tags: google-app-engine

We have a suite of UI tests that run against a local AppEngine dev server in a CI environment. The first step we perform in each of the tests is to clear the local datastore and reset it with known data. We do this in code via a java servlet.

We are running into an issue (outlined [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7282)) that started in AppEngine 1.6.4. As the tests progress, the data setup step takes longer and longer. It starts out at around 10 seconds for the first few tests and by the end, it takes over a minute for each one.

So I'm looking for alternatives for setting up and tearing down data for our UI tests. For example, can I keep a local_db.bin file on hand and "detach/attach" it before each test? [I suspect no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552101/how-do-i-add-some-test-data-to-appengine-local-datastore-file), at least not while the dev server is still running. And I don't think it's feasible to stop and restart the dev server before each test.

So any other ideas?

Comment: How are you clearing and resetting your datastore?  Have you tried just deleting the datastore files?

Comment: We have a servlet that clears each entity kind and another that sets up various test data. We could delete the file (or replace it with one with known data) but that means we'll need to stop the dev server at the end of each test and restart it before the next one, doesn't it? Can it be replaced while the dev server is running?